# find T such that $\ f(P)-f(Q) = \nabla f(T)(P-Q)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let$\ f(x,y,z)=4xz -y^2 +z^2$ be a differentiable function, let$\ P=(0,1,1)$ and$\ Q=(1,3,2)$. Find$\ T$ such that $\ f(P)-f(Q) = \nabla f(T)(P-Q)$

What I did:

$\ f(P)=0$, $\ f(Q)=3$, $\ (P-Q)=(-1,-2,-1)$, $\nabla f(P-Q)=(-4z, 4y, -4x+2z)$

Let $\ T=(a,b,c)$ then$\ f(P)-f(Q) = \nabla f(T)(P-Q)$ if and only if

$\ -3 = (-4c, 4b, -4a-2c)$, I'm stuck at this point, how can I determine this?

Looking for some advice, thanks!

Comment: You have a scalar $-3$ equal to a vector $(-4c,4b,-4a-2c)$. This should be setting off alarm bells. I believe you are missing a dot product in the original equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f$ takes a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and returns a scalar in $\mathbb{R}$. The left hand side of the expression is a scalar, and so is the right hand side, because the product is a dot product:
\begin{align*}
f(P)-f(Q) &= \nabla f(T) \cdot (P-Q) \\
0 - 3 &= \langle 4z, -2y, 4x + 2z \rangle \cdot \langle 0-1, 1-3, 1-2 \rangle \\
-3 &= \langle 4z, -2y, 4x + 2z \rangle \cdot \langle -1, -2, -1 \rangle \\
&= -4z+2y-4x-2z \\
3 &= 4x-2y+6z 
\end{align*}
This defines a plane of points, any of which will satisfy the relation, so we can choose $(0,0,1/2)$

Answer (score 1):

Following from what I did:

Let $\ g(t)=(1, 3, 2)+t(-1, -2, -1) = (1-t, 3-2t, 2-t)$

$\nabla f(1-t, 3-2t, 2-t) = (-4t+8, 4t-6, -6t+8)$

$\ -3 = (-4t+8, 4t-6, -6t+8)(-1, -2, -1) = (4t-8, -8t+12, 6t-8)$ if and only if $\ t=1/2$, substitute$\ t$ in the function$\ g $ and

$\ T=g(t)=(\frac{1}{2}, 2,\frac{3}{2})$ is the answer